# Using FFmpeg or other libraries on an ARM SoC without OS layer?

Tags: arm, library

I would like to use [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) on an ARM SoC to perform some decoding. Now, as I understand conventionally everybody uses it within an OS environment. However, I was wondering whether it is possible to also use FFmpeg or any other library without an OS layer?

I mean, it is possible to, let's say write C code, which is compiled into executables, that can directly run on an ARM processor without OS. So, it should also be possible to statically bind any other library source code into the executable and run it without OS, right?

Comment: You can take references from the below link from the NXP forum. https://community.nxp.com/t5/i-MX-RT-Knowledge-Base/Application-Note-AN12562-Development-of-H-264-video-decode-on-RT/ta-p/1114085 It has application notes for IMXRT1050 and Demo application as well.

Answer (score 3):

That is of course possible, BUT ...

that ffmpeg code will likely make some library functions (reading bloks of data from the mpeg file?) that would be provided by the OS. In a non-OS ('bare metal') situation you must somehow provide those functions.

Comment: I see - so theoretically yes, practically more involved?

Comment: I'd agree with that - any SoC powerful enough to do ffmpeg stuff is going to be intended to run some sort of OS, so you're going to end up with a lot of loose ends to join to ffmpeg, and probably a lot of work just to get the SoC up & running without the help of numerous drivers.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I think it would be very much possible. I cannot say for sure of course, but I have spent good two weeks on integrating FFmpeg audio decoding into our main Qt project, so I know what I'm saying.

It turns out, that the data I/O is completely customizable using your own callbacks. This enables you to read from / write to any device there is.

The decoding process of say an audio stream is as follows:

1. Reading the data and demuxing of individual streams is done using the *avformat* part of FFmpeg. This is where custom I/O callbacks come into play. You just point the *AVIOContext* structure's function pointers to where your I/O handles are.
2. Decoding is then done in the *avcodec* part of FFmpeg. Just plug the demuxed packet into a decoder (avcodec_decode_audio4() I think).
3. You end up with raw audio that you can directly use with, say a DAC.

---

One thing that concerns me, is that in the FFmpeg manual they mention, that *certain codecs may use threads*. I do not know any specifics, nor what system API is used for thread management. But you may point you in a direction.

---

> So, it should also be possible to statically bind any other library source code

And yes, it should be (is) possible to statically link in other libraries on a raw MCU.